# Sample simulation to get a distribution with Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: random, integer, wolfram-mathematica, simulation, distribution

I need some help with my Mathematica homework..
I want to get the mean of some random numbers from 0 to 10 and that each time for a higher amount of samples (from 10 to 20). Then I would like to plot it somehow as a distribution of all means or if that's not possible as a List Plot. I have to show that with a rising amount of samples, the mean becomes more and more correct. That's what I already have..

```
For[i = 10, i < 20, i++, Print[Mean[RandomInteger[10, i]]]]
```

I'm grateful for every help!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, and you need first to do some effort by yourself. If you can't even get started, ask your teacher for help. Isolate your questions into specific programming snippets, and then search the for answers. In case you need a course or tutorial, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask it. We wish you good luck in your study. See: [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Thanks, I will try it this way!

Answer (score 1):

`For` loops do not return results, so they have to be collected.
 `Print` won't help.

```
output = {};
For[i = 10, i < 20000, i++, AppendTo[output, Mean[RandomInteger[10, i]]]]
ListPlot[output, AxesLabel -> {"Samples", "Mean"}]
```

[image]

Better to use `Table` instead of `For`.  `Table` *does* return results.

```
output = Table[Mean[RandomInteger[10, i]], {i, 10, 20000}];
ListPlot[output, AxesLabel -> {"Samples", "Mean"}]
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it didn't include the `For`-based calculation at all.